# How to handle plus-minus with the trigonometric identity of $\cot^2(x)=\csc^2(x)-1$?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

I was originally answering the question from my textbook:

> Given that $x=\csc(6y)$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $x$

I know how to differentiate it with respect to $y$ then do some substitutions to get it in terms of $x$. But when I use the identity$$1+\cot^2(x)=\csc^2(x)$$
Rearranged to
$$\cot^2(x)=\csc^2(x)-1$$
I'll have to take the square root from here. It could be $\pm$. Normally, my textbook gives me a range to work with but hasn't this time. And the solution given for it simply omits the $\pm$ entirely, instead going straight for the positive. Sometimes I see an explanation for it, sometimes not. I've sort of accepted the solutions to examples before but I don't know why I can't seem to reproduce it this time. 
Perhaps I am not seeing something basic and in plain sight.

---

Edit:
So I understand that inverse functions do not simply mean that you take 1 over that function. Therefore, $\csc^{-1}(x)$ would be derived from
$$\frac{1}{\sin(x)}=y$$
$$\frac{1}{y}=\sin(x)$$
$$\arcsin \left(\frac{1}{y} \right)=x$$
$$\csc^{-1}(x)=\arcsin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right)$$
[image]

From desmos, I get this graph. I understand why the domain doesn't include any real value of $x$ from -1 to 1 since the domain of the inverse function is the range of the original function. But I don't think I've deduced anything. Rather, when I tried taking the derivative of $\arcsin$, while I know what the derivative of $\arcsin$ is, the proof for it uses the same idea of taking the square root in those trigonometric identities. So I'm back to square one here unfortunately.

Comment: You're right that you should consider both roots of the equation, but only the positive root will work with the traditional domain/range of $\csc^{-1}$. Think about the domain and range of $\csc^{-1}$, and what the sign of the derivative of $\csc^{-1}$ should be. Can you try it out and see where that leads you? Edit the question to show us where you end up.

Comment: What does the graph tell you about the derivative of $\csc^{-1}$?